# Why typescript is throw typing error: Property 'customSelect' does not exist on type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>'

Tags: typescript, knex.js, nrwl-nx

I got an error:

```
typing error: Property 'customSelect' does not exist on type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>'
```

[From the function](https://github.com/wizardnet972/nx-knex/blob/main/libs/my-knex/src/lib/my-knex.ts#L10):

```
console.log({ inCreateConnection: ins.customSelect })
```

I add this interface in `typing.d.ts` to support `customSelect` just as say in [knex docs](https://knexjs.org/#typescript-support):

```
// typings.d.ts
// from: https://knexjs.org/#typescript-support 
//       Extending Query Builder
import { Knex as KnexOriginal } from 'knex';

declare module 'knex' {
  namespace Knex {
    interface QueryBuilder {
      customSelect<TRecord, TResult>(
        value: number
      ): KnexOriginal.QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult>;
    }
  }
}
```

The typings isn't work in both files:
https://github.com/wizardnet972/nx-knex/blob/main/libs/my-knex/src/lib/my-knex.ts#L10 and https://github.com/wizardnet972/nx-knex/blob/main/libs/product-api/src/lib/product-api.ts#L6

```
import knex from 'knex';

export const createConnection = () => {
  const ins = knex({
    connection: {
      host: 'localhost',
    },
  });

  console.log({ inCreateConnection: ins.customSelect }) /// <--- typing error: Property 'customSelect' does not exist on type 'Knex<any, unknown[]>'

  return ins;
};
```

This problem is about typing and it's not supposed to run. but the typings are supposed to work.

Why typescript doesn't recognize the function?

Comment: You need to include your declaration file in the `tsconfig.json` of your project.

Comment: @AnthonyMa I include `d.ts` file in the `tsconfig.json` at the `my-knex` lib. still not works. this is what you mean?

Comment: Then you're not extending the right module. The init knex function returns `KnexType`, you're extending `KnexType.QueryBuilder`. try `ins("tableName").customSelect`.

Comment: is this solved? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: no. but I found a workaround: put `declare module .....` in ts file. (could be index.ts).